# Link to User's Facebook Wall From iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, deep-linking

Been looking for guidance but most of what I find on here and the web is "How to post to Facebook from iOS app". Mine question is different.

I have an app that has multiple users.

If user1 is looking at user2's profile on my iOS app, I would like to have a button on user2's profile that (when pressed by user1) would open user1's Facebook App displaying user2's Facebook Wall with a "back" or "done" button to take user1 back to my app.

I would think this would be easy but I can't find any information on it.

1. How do I get the url or information to get to the users Facebook Wall when that users creates an account on my iOS app?
2. How do I then create the link that will open the Facebook App and display said user's Facebook wall?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I first followed this Tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/

Then I modified it for my needs.

Here is my code below for my app

In AppDelegate.m

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
}
...
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
              sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

In CreateAccountConnectSocialMediaViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface CreateAccountConnectSocialMediaViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *socialMediaView;
    - (IBAction)nextButton:(UIButton *)sender;
    - (IBAction)openProfileButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

In CreateAccountConnectSocialMediaViewController.m

```
@interface CreateAccountConnectSocialMediaViewController ()
@property FBLoginView *fbLoginButton;
@property NSString *fbUserID;
@end

@implementation CreateAccountConnectSocialMediaViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create CUSTOM FB Button
    self.fbLoginButton = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    for (id loginObject in self.fbLoginButton.subviews)
    {
        if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FB_Hover.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        }
        if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *loginLabel =  loginObject;
            loginLabel.text = @"";
            loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    self.fbLoginButton.delegate = self;
    self.fbLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.fbLoginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 46);
    [self.socialMediaView addSubview:self.fbLoginButton];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Change the ICON to denote the user is logged in
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    for (id loginObject in self.fbLoginButton.subviews)
    {
        if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *loginButton =  loginObject;
            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FB_Static.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        }
        if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *loginLabel =  loginObject;
            loginLabel.text = @"";
            loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

}

//Grab the users Apped Scoped ID, to use in going to his/her page later
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    self.fbUserID = user.objectID;
}

Change the ICON to denote the user is NOT logged in
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    for (id loginObject in self.fbLoginButton.subviews)
    {
        if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FB_Hover.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        }
        if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel * loginLabel =  loginObject;
            loginLabel.text = @"";
            loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

}

-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


- (IBAction)nextButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    //Go to next CreateAccount View Controller
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"accountCreatedSegue1" sender:self];
}

//Open the user's profile in the native FB App or
//the browser if the native FB app doesn't exist
- (IBAction)openProfileButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@", self.fbUserID];
    NSLog(@"urlString = %@", urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
@end
```